# Having trouble installing Mimio Studio smartboard software

Tags: package-management

I am trying to get Mimio Studio installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Mimio Studio is a hardware+software system that can be used with a projector to create a virtual whiteboard on just about any flat surface.

When I installed Chrome, I used dpkg -i, apt-get update, install -f, which from what I understand, is supposed to take care of dependencies issues, so I tried something similar when I ran into trouble with Mimio, but no luck. Additionally, in my attempt to install Mimio, I enabled architecture i386.

I am a huge noob, so I dont really know what kinds of details to give when asking my question, or what kinds of keywords to search for online.

What do I need to tell you?

Comment: I can see it in my system monitor, processes, and when I right click , properties, I get even more information. Is it something in there that I should be looking for? It is using 12% of my RAM right now, according to System Monitor.

Comment: I am beginning to think it might be an Ubuntu issue, not an issue with Mimio. I am able to get Mimio installed perfectly on a VM, but I want it on my host machine for many reasons. When I right click on the process in System Monitor, I get all kinds of groovey information. I just dont know what to do with any of it... From my limited experience, it looks a lot like the program did install, and based on the fact that it is taking up 12% of my CPU, I am also pretty sure the program is actually starting up, but it is not displaying, or becoming usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a suggestion of one of my students' parent who uses Linux professionally, I did

$ ./mimio-notebook

 and got

 Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"

 Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"

 Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

 Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

Which I am not sure if that tells me about the next step, but one of my coworkers found a site,  http://www.edugeek.net/forums/nix/132648-mimio-ubuntu-13-10-a.html , which outlines the details on how to fix, and it worked!

FIX:

 1) $ sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 gcc-4.6-base:i386 libstdc++5:i386 libstdc++6:i386

 2) $ sudo apt-get install -f

 3) $ sudo chown -R youruser:youruser /home/youruser/.mimio

I thought doing 

 $ sudo apt-get install -f

 during the install would cover these dependncies, but I guess not.

 still can't figure out why I was able to install in VMs all day, but could not install on my host OS, but it works now, so great!

Answer (score 0):

As far I can understand [Mimio have Linux version for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://news.mimio.boxlight.com/mimiostudio-software-download).

After submitting registration form they provide two deb-files:

1. English - `mimio-studio_11.53-en_i386.deb` (267 Mb)
2. Multi-Language - `mimio-studio_11.53-intl_i386.deb` (616 Mb)

So one of them should be installed with `apt-get install`:

```
sudo apt-get install ./mimio-studio_11.53*.deb
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to install the mimio-studio_11.53-en_i386.deb file. I actually did get it to install. Kind of... I can see it  in my programs list, and when I click to start it, it blinks on the launcher for a few seconds, and then disappears. I wish I had a more technical explanation for you. 

I did enable i386, and do install -f, then repeated dpkg -i

I also tried as you said, sudo apt-get install

Comment: I do not have such hardware. So I hope that installation procedure is not problem. We installed it in almost same way. If you do not have broken packages then it was installed successfully (check with `sudo apt-get check` and `sudo apt-get install -f`). You could try to launch `mimio-` executables (autocomplete correct executable names with `<Tab>` key) from terminal and see error output. Or if your are legal user, you can contact Mimio support.

Comment: Weird. I even tried removing it, and doing autoremove to hopefully delete the packages originally installed. and then complete re-download and reinstall. I did read their website, and although it lists a Linux software download, it does not list Linux as a supported OS. I am finding very limited documentation online about this.

Im still leaning towards it being a problem on my end, maybe how I installed Ubuntu? The reason I dont think it is on the Mimio end is because I have installed this same software many times before, and never had a problem then.

Comment: I wound up reinstalling ubuntu, and that still did not resolve whatever issue it is. I installed it in ubuntu in virtual box, and that worked just fine, no problems at all. So it will install in vbox, but not on my native OS. I even tried installing wine, so I could try the windows installer, but the file is in .msi, or something that is not .exe .

Weird.

Comment: I installed a fresh Ubuntu 16 onto a different hard drive. This time HDD, where my main drive is an SSD. Still getting the same thing- program installs. It starts up, and remains in the processes until I end process. Still shows in the list when I dpkg --list it. Fun fact, ubuntu installs on and boots up faster as a VM on an SSD than it does as the main OS on an HDD.

Is there some kind of way to record the steps of the Mimio software starting up fully in my VM, and then record the Mimio software getting stuck in my main OS, and I could see where it might be happening?

Comment: I noticed in the processes for the working VM install of Mimio, there is a mimio-mimiosys id 12885 process that does not appear when my main OS fails to fully start the program. I read about other OS users also having trouble with their mimiosys file. How would I find a new mimiosys file?

Comment: Dear @GordonBiersch. I answered mostly about howto install *.deb packages, I'm not familiar with Mimio-devices and software. I downloaded english deb-package and installed it on VM when was writing my answer. I do not remember which processes were started after install.
For debugging you may try [sysdig](https://sysdig.com/opensource/) or something similar. I do not know about mimio-mimiosys and other parts.

Comment: thanks for your replies. I got a response from the customer service rep at Boxlight, or Mimio or whoever does their CS. I'm hoping they'll come out with a 64-bit version soon. That might resolve the issue.